# create re-usable dropdown list on same page asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, sqldatasource

I am creating a large form which re-uses the same dropdown-list of employees multiple times. it is a dynamic dropdown-list which uses a sqldatasource to get the employee list from a sql server db. Is there any way of creating a control or something else which will help me in this situation. I need to be able to change the ID of the control every time I use the dropdown-list. I dont want to keep creating a separate dropdown-list with sqldatasource 15 times in the same form. Any Ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user control (`.ascx`) sounds like exactly what you need.

Check out [Walkthrough: Creating Reusable Elements with ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3457w616%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks. I have created a control which is a dynamic dropdown list. how do I access the selected value of the control to insert into db. if it was a normal dropdown list, I would use - 'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LearnSkills", Dropdownlist1.Text);' but I cant use Dropdownlist1.Text when using a user control.

Comment: You need to create a read-only (`getter` only) property in your user control that will expose the `string` value of the value selected in the drop down list, like this: public string SelectedValue
{
    get
    {
        return dropdownlist1.Text;
    }
}